# Copying files from one folder to another in Amazon S3 bucket using php

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-s3

how do I copy all files from a directory(folder) to a different directory in Amazon S3 bucket using Codeigniter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out S3 tools: http://s3tools.org/s3cmd.

You can install it on your server, then you've got all sorts of command line tools for manipulating stuff in your s3 buckets.

Once you have it installed, you could call s3cmd's "put" (to move a a local file to an s3 bucket) with php's `exec()`, which executes shell commands:

```
exec('s3cmd put /my-local-dir/some_file.txt s3://my-s3-bucket/some-dir/some_file.txt');
```

More about [exec() here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

Comment: for example I have a folder called Test1, I want to copy everything to Test2. How do I use it with PHP. Both Test1 and Test2 are Amazon S3 bucket's folder. For example the path are as follows: Test1=aa/bb/cc Test2=aa/qq/cc.

Comment: You can't do it with only PHP.  You will also need another tool, like s3cmd, or [s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon)

Comment: Ok, if I have this already installed how do I do it with php/codeigniter.

Comment: sorry for this, but kind of need this asap